# Troubleshooting connectivity when curl returns 'empty reply' from a server on my computer only

Tags: networking, mac-osx, curl, malware

For whatever reason, my computer (Mac OS X 10.11.1) cannot fetch a webpage from a website using curl when it works fine on other computers. Also ping works but curl doesn't:

```
$ ping www.latex-tutorial.com
PING latex-tutorial.com (162.252.172.25): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 162.252.172.25: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=76.116 ms
64 bytes from 162.252.172.25: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=74.538 ms
64 bytes from 162.252.172.25: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=90.379 ms
^C
--- latex-tutorial.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 74.538/80.344/90.379/7.125 ms
```

Now when curl was executed on the problematic machine several times:

```
$ curl http://www.latex-tutorial.com
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl -Lv http://www.latex-tutorial.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.latex-tutorial.com/
*   Trying 2a02:748:a800:162:252:172:25::...
* Connected to www.latex-tutorial.com (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.latex-tutorial.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host www.latex-tutorial.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

When I execute the same command on a different Mac laptop (same version) in the same network, I do get a correct html web page every time. What could possibly be wrong with my machine? I did download a few things off the internet where my machine could have potentially contracted a virus/malware, but my antivirus program wasn't able to detect anything.

Can anyone point me to where I should start looking for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `-4` option to your `curl` command line.  Alternatively, try `http://162.252.172.25` and see what you get.  The `ping` is using that address, which is an IPv4 address.  The `curl` is using IPv6, with an address starting with `2a02`.  Not all IPv6 stacks are equally robust - perhaps yours has connection issues.

Comment: Thanks! -4 option makes this work, but when I try with 'http://162.252.172.25'  I get "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" and the resulting redirection still leaves me with "Empty reply from server". I'm a bit unsure why this is happening.

Comment: After seeing some strange logs in my system log about Avast screwing up with my network, I uninstalled it and now the network is running fine. Not installing an antivirus program from now on... Anyways thanks for your help! :)